# git desktop pop up over and over again in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

i'm using IntelliJ with git desktop. And there's a minor issue that git desktop pop up whenever I change a file. Does anyone know how to change that.

Comment: Which popup exactly are you talking about?

Comment: when i change any file in the project, git desktop pop up, and then i minimize it, i change another file, it pop up again

Comment: This doesn't answer the question I asked.

Comment: oh, sorry, it pop up the git desktop it self

Comment: @Lirus What executable file did you configure as the Git client in IntelliJ IDEA Version Control Settings? It should point to the command line `git.exe` if you are on Windows.